# Why do Blue Morpho butterflies appear blue?

Tags: optics, visible-light, diffraction, biophysics

Blue Morpho butterflies are said to display structural coloration, but how do their scales cause light to diffract in such a way that they appear blue?

I just don't understand how it's blue light that comes off and not any other color. Does the width of the ridges in the scales correspond to the wavelength of blue light?

Comment: Color changes are not simply diffraction, as the color is in one to one correspondence with frequency. It could be most of white light is absorbed by its skin and only blue reflected

Comment: @annav Thanks for the response, but how exactly do the butterflies specifically reflect only blue light? Are there slits in their scales that cause constructive interference?

Comment: Wikipedia has pages on both Structural Coloration and the Morpho butterfly, both of which explain the mechanisms involved.  What about those pages do you not understand ?

Comment: Thin film effects are well known across the butterflies and birds. Constructive/destructive interference is the key.

Comment: @StephenG I just don't understand how it's blue light that comes off and not any other color. I understand the concept of interference. Does the width of the ridges in the scales correspond to the wavelength of blue light? Using n Lambda = d sin theta

Comment: I'd suggest you add that comment to the question (use the "edit" option) as people don't always read commenst (and the system can "clean" them anytime - i.e. it could be deleted later).

Comment: [Brilliant iridescence of Morpho butterfly wing scales is due to both a thin film lower lamina and a multilayered upper lamina](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00359-016-1084-1)